# field double quotes php postgresql

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, double-quotes, mesa

Hello everyone I have a problem with a table in their fields has double quotes ("")

[image]

When I want to make an update to a field without quotation marks, for example:

```
 $rs = pg_query("UPDATE tbl_audit
   SET UserName='admin'
 WHERE pk_audit='549';");
```

Postgresql I said to the field (UserName) does not exist in the table

but when I put the quotes like this:

```
    $rs = pg_query("UPDATE tbl_audit
   SET "UserName"='admin'
 WHERE pk_audit='549'");
```

It says : **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'UserName' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\postgrado\admin\update.php on line 35**

I do not understand, when I do this from the SQL window pgadmin (no PHP), I work successfully

```
UPDATE tbl_audit
SET "UserName"='admin'
WHERE pk_audit='549';
```

Comment: Escape the inner double quotes or (use outer single quotes and parameterized queries).

Comment: as I make the parameterized query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could escape the "inner" double quotes by using a backslash:

```
$rs = pg_query("UPDATE tbl_audit
                SET \"UserName\" = 'admin'
                WHERE pk_audit='549';");
```